# Pop up message if cell contains text

Tags: excel, vba

I created a sheet, where data for different ranges is pulled from another sheet using many different formulas.

In one of cell range (D11:G15), the formula gives names of approvers, yet, in the original document, their names always have prefixes sometimes numbers, sometimes numbers and letters
e.g.: WL11-Adam Smith, 12-Adam Smith etc.

We introduced a new process that requires additional actions if one of approvers is a particular person:

I need a **pop out message box with instructions that appears if the string in above mentioned range contains names of those approvers**.
Let's say Adam Smith and Diana Rose, but as I mentioned the names in range appear through formula and they contain not only name itself but also a series of other characters.
Additionally, this macro should be triggered **automatically** if a person appears in given range.

[image]

In general, our agents input just country and commodity code. All the rest is pulled from other documents.
The range with approvers are in column D to G but it can be various rows from 1 to 4, 6 rows.

Updated code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   
Dim people, c As Variant people = Array("Adam Smith", "Diana Rose") 
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D11:G15") 
For Each person In people If c.Value2 Like "*" & person & "*" Then 
MsgBox ("Your instructions") 
End If 
Next person 
Next c  
End Sub
```

I get

> Type mismatch (Error 13)

on line:

```
If c.Value2 Like "*" & person & "*" Then
```

I tried doing it with data validation.
I also tried with if function that appears in an empty cell, but the instructions are too long and could not finish it that way.

Comment: The code as shown in the question shouldn't compile. There has to be a linebreak before `people=...` Furthermore you have to define the variable `person`

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot wrong with the code you've posted, other than a couple of missing line breaks and a declare.

However, if there is a cell within the tested range that contains an error, it will throw an error 13. You can trap this with the `IsError` function like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim people As Variant, person As Variant, c As Variant
    people = Array("Adam Smith", "Diana Rose")
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D11:G15")
        For Each person In people
            If IsError(c) Then
                ' do nothing or advise there is a cell error
            Else
                If c.Value2 Like "*" & person & "*" Then
                    MsgBox ("Your instructions")
                End If
            End If
        Next person
    Next c
End Sub
```

If you only want the code to execute when a change has been made *within the test range* and only report once per change - then you could use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim people As Variant, person As Variant, c As Variant, testrange As Range
    Set testrange = Intersect(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D11:G15"), Target)
    If Not (testrange Is Nothing) Then
        people = Array("Adam Smith", "Diana Rose")
        For Each c In testrange
            For Each person In people
                If IsError(c) Then
                    ' do nothing or advise there is a cell error
                Else
                    If c.Value2 Like "*" & person & "*" Then
                        MsgBox ("Your instructions")
                    End If
                End If
            Next person
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: IT WORKED!
Thank you so much @CLR, yes IsError saved the code!
YOU DA BEST!